# Eclipse CDT autocomplete for tradtional C identifiers

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Eclipse autocomplete works OK for CamelCaseIdentifiers.  But it is completely useless for MORE_TRADITONAL_style_identifiers which have upper case prefexes and are separated by "_"s.

Something like MTsi should match the latter, just like CCI matches the former.

Is there a way to do that?  I could not find any preference.

Incidentally there is M*T*st*id.

Comment: Can you provide some more details? Ideally, a complete code example, where you're invoking the autocomplete, what completion proposals you'd like to get, and what completion proposals you actually get.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this already works, as long as you capitalize every letter in the query:

```
int MORE_TRADITIONAL_style_identifier();

int main() {
    int x = MTSI/*complete*/    // <-- completes MORE_TRADITIONAL_style_identifier
}
```

But it doesn't if some of the letters in the query are not capitalized, such as `MTsi`. I think capital letters are the signal to the matching algorithm that two subsequent letters are potentially the beginnings of two different segments, whereas a sequence of lowercase letters like `si` just expects to find that substring verbatim.

If you feel the matching algorithm could be improved to handle mixed-case queries like this better, you could consider [filing a bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT) and/or [contributing a patch](https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/contributing).